# searching for records using Full text search across multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

```
SELECT A.a, B.b, akt.[Rank] + bkt.[Rank] /2  AS [Rank]
FROM B b
INNER JOIN Publication a ON a.Id = b.Id
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(A, a, 'search text') akt ON a.Id = akt.[Key]
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(B, b, 'search text') bkt ON b.Id = bkt.[Key] 
ORDER BY [Rank] DESC

UNION
SELECT A.a, null as B.b, akt.[Rank] as [Rank]
FROM A a
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(A, a, 'search text') akt ON a.Id = akt.[Key]

UNION
SELECT null as A.a, B.b, bkt.[Rank] as [Rank]
FROM B b
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(A, a, 'search text') akt ON a.Id = akt.[Key]
```

The above query is for searching records (using rankings) across two tables.

**The first query :** Only those records will be displayed where the search text is in both the columns  of the two tables.

**Second query :** Only those records where searchtext is only in column a of table A

**Third query :**  Only those records where searchtext is only in column b of table B

My question is: If I have to search across 4 or 5 tables, the number of UNIONS will increase like crazy. It will be too complicated and slow as well.

So, Is there any other method which could reduce these UNIONS?
I tried Views, but they cannot be full text indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use full join

```
SELECT A.a, B.b, "Use case for calculating rank"
    FROM B b
    FULL JOIN A a ON b.Id = a.Id
WHERE
    a.[columnname] = 'search text' OR
    b.[columnname] = 'search text'
```

Check http://codesnout.com/SQLSample/SQL-FULL-JOIN.php

Comment: Thank you Rain, This is working, but the ranking is coming only for those records which are in both the columns, For others, Rank = NULL

Comment: Yes, rank will be null. Thats why I told you to use casing to calculate rank. Please show the exact script you are using, then I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.FK_Publication_ID, b.PageNumber as PageNumber, b.SearchText as SearchText, a.Title as Title , 
TitleSearch.[Rank] + PubSearch.[Rank] * 10000
  AS [Rank]
FROM PublicationSearch 
INNER JOIN Publication a ON b.FK_Publication_Id = a.Id
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(PublicationSearch, SearchText, "searchtext") PubSearch ON b.Id = PubSearch.[Key] 
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(Publication, Title, "searchtext") TitleSearch ON a.Id = TitleSearch.[Key] 
WHERE b.FK_ContentType_Id IN (SELECT * FROM UF_CSVToTable(@Options))

UNION 


SELECT  a.Id, null as PageNumber, null as Searchtext, a.Title as Title, TitleSearch.[Rank] * 100  AS [Rank]
FROM Publication a
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(Publication,Title, "searchtext") TitleSearch ON a.Id = TitleSearch.[Key]


UNION

SELECT b.FK_Publication_ID, b.PageNumber as PageNumber, b.SearchText as SearchText, null as Title, 
PubSearch.[Rank] 
  AS [Rank] 
FROM PublicationSearch b
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(PublicationSearch, SearchText, "searchtext") PubSearch ON b.Id = PubSearch.[Key] 

ORDER BY [Rank] DESC
```

The above is using UNION

Below is as you suggested

SELECT b.FK_Publication_ID, b.PageNumber as PageNumber, b.SearchText as SearchText, a.Title as Title as ContentType ,

```
TitleSearch.[Rank] * 100  (Ranking, dont know how to do it here)
  AS [Rank]
FROM PublicationSearch b
INNER JOIN Publication a ON b.FK_Publication_Id = a.Id
JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(PublicationSearch, SearchText, "searchtext")PubSearch ON b.Id = PubSearch.[Key] 
FULL JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(Publication, Title, "searchtext")TitleSearch ON a.Id = TitleSearch.[Key] 

order by [RANK] desc
```

Heres, the exact script. Using Full Join, I get the records from BOTH table AND records from only PublicationSearch table BUT NOT only from Publication table

Also, the records found in both tables should be ranked higher, then records from only Publication table AND THEN records from PublicationSerach table

Thanks..